# Image is not keep the ratio, how to keep it?

Tags: android, imageview, stretch

I just created a GUI with only one ImageView. The code below:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:background="@drawable/exam_list_bg"
    android:gravity="top|center" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/exam_icon_failed" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**Some more info:**
- exam_icon_failed.png (97x175)
- i use Galaxy Nexus as preview device (in eclipse)

**And the problem:**
- In preview screen, i see that the image was OK (keep ratio, no stretch..) But when i install in phone (same screen size with preview device) -> the image was stretched.

Could you give some advice for this case? i want to keep the image ratio. Many thanks!

Comment: I suppose the problem has to do with the TableLayout. Have you tried a different Layout? What if you use a simple LinearLayout and add your image - is it stretched there too?

Comment: Is the image stretched horizontally or vertically? Is it stretched to screen-width or -height or just a little bit "out of shape"?

Comment: Hi, i have tried and it didn't working. How ever i tried with other image also and see that it ok. is it possible if the issue come from image size?

P/s: for your question: It stretched horizontal and just a little bit "out of shape".

Comment: Can you post a picture of how it looks like?

Comment: Hello, sorry for late but at this time i can't take a picture with ddms. Here is the link for preview in eclipse and original pic:
http://i1312.photobucket.com/albums/t530/langhoangal/myQuestions/preview_zps71ab0a39.png -> preview. http://i1312.photobucket.com/albums/t530/langhoangal/myQuestions/exam_icon_failed_zps5be397d5.png -> original. I will use memo program to take a device screenshot now.

Comment: WT.. :(. the image that taken by memo program is ok, the image is ok, but it isn't what i can see in my device @@. I make sure that it stretch here, in device on my hand :| http://i1312.photobucket.com/albums/t530/langhoangal/myQuestions/2013-08-11-00-26-54_zps9f8a278a.jpg

Comment: Doesn't look stretched to me ...

Comment: Here is what i see: http://i1312.photobucket.com/albums/t530/langhoangal/myQuestions/real_zpscb195f00.png

Comment: Do you have any idea please? sine what i see is http://i1312.photobucket.com/albums/t530/langhoangal/myQuestions/real_zpscb195f00.png i take it with webcam.

Comment: try it may help change your width/height one attribute to match_parent and set scale type = "center"..

Comment: It looks like the original you posted. Do you want it to fill the whole screen perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your help.
   Finally, i found that it come from my desktop (exactly screen resolution).

When i view the original image with my desktop, it look like a square. I have took a picture from my desktop here: http://i1312.photobucket.com/albums/t530/langhoangal/myQuestions/original_inDesktop_zpsbab06700.jpg

But when i open it by my laptop, i can see it like that (i think you see like that): http://i1312.photobucket.com/albums/t530/langhoangal/myQuestions/original_inLaptop_zpsbf19a22c.jpg -> same with what i can see in my phone.

So, the problem is my computer screen display wrong. :) I have tried to adjust resolution and it ok now, i can see exactly what display on phone.

Many thanks for all of you!
Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

Add [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) to your ImageView like so:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/exam_icon_failed" />
```

Comment: I have tried with your solution but it didn't work. Do you have any solution else?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your problem correctly. This solution will make sure the original image aspect ratio is kept and will either shrink the image to fit or display the image at its original resolution if it's smaller than the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/exam_icon_failed"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

And apply 9-patch to your image if possible. Hope this helps.

Comment: It this didnt work, I suggest you better have a larger image to fit with you phone screen-size, otherwise it will keep stretching. Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

change your image view like

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scaleType="center" 
   android:src="@drawable/exam_icon_failed" />
```

may help you and someone..